# how to Android webview Change the content of the page

Tags: android, webview

Android use webview to load web pages such as facebook I would like to load the video tag in the label below the button, such as the following figure:

[image]

How to do like this?

Comment: actually they use jsoup library to manipulate the code and then use manipulated code into webview

Comment: oh. I have tried to use jsoup. But in webview click into the next page when how to operate? Can you give an example